# Does finish() unregister broadcast receivers?

Tags: android

I've set up a BroadcastReceiver as a way for one activity to stop another.  The activity I want to stop looks something like this:

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "TestActivity";
    private Context mContext = null;

    private final BroadcastReceiver mQuitReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (action.equals("finish_activity")) {
                mLogUtil.d(TAG, "onReceive() finishing...");
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mContext = this;
        mLogUtil.d(TAG, "onCreate()");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).registerReceiver(mQuitReceiver, new IntentFilter("finish_activity"));
        // Other initialization stuff...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy()
    {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mContext).unregisterReceiver(mQuitReceiver);
        // Other de-initialization stuff...
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

And I finish it from another activity via:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("finish_activity");
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

My question is, do I actually need to un-register that receiver manually if the receiver is tied to the activity instance anyway?  Or does the finish() method clean that up for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to unregister the receiver, since it isn't really tied to the activity.  As you can see in the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java#4847), finish doesn't know about receivers you've registered, so there's nothing it can really do to automate this.

To expand on this, as you can see in the [LocalBroadcastManager source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.java#99) the application context you pass to `getInstance()` isn't actually used for anything, it's the application context that's used.  So the LocalBroadcastManager doesn't have any sort of reference to your Activity to know it's lifecycle.

Comment: Oh so the instance of the receiver is tied to the activity, but the act of registering is independent of the activities.  Thanks :)